# App crash when button clicked using ontouchlistener

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, ontouchlistener

my bluetooth app was going well until i used onTouchListener method , when i click on the bottom , the app crashes . I have several buttons and all of them end up crashing , bellow is part of my mainactivity code  and the crash log, can you help me find the error? if the question is to vague or lacks information , please tell me .

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button  forward_btn,forward_left_btn , forward_right_btn , reverse_btn , reverse_right_btn , reverse_left_btn , btnConexao ;
    public static final int SOLICITA_ATIVACAO = 1; // é o codigo numero 1 , é diferenciado o codigo pq pode haver varias solicitações na msma tela
    public static final int SOLICITA_CONEXAO = 2;

    BluetoothAdapter meuBluetoothAdapter=null; //declarar o meu adptador bluetooth
    BluetoothDevice meuDevice=null;
    BluetoothSocket meuSocket=null;// faz transiçao dos dados




    boolean conexao =  false; //variavel para a conexao que indica se a conexao está em andamento ou nao

    private OutputStream outputStream;
    private static String MAC = null;
    String command; //string variable that will store value to be transmitted to the bluetooth module

    UUID MEU_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"); // canal de comunicaçao bluetooth , UUID- ID do canal
//protocolo Rfcomm



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        forward_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.forward_btn); //definir botoes e associar ao ficheiro xml
        forward_left_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.forward_left_btn);
        forward_right_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.forward_right_btn);
        reverse_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reverse_btn);
        reverse_left_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reverse_left_btn);
        reverse_right_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reverse_right_btn);
        btnConexao = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConexao);



        forward_btn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            // comando para o botao frente , forward button
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {   // comandos bluetooth correspondentes do arduino

                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) //MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN é quando botao é segurado
                {
                    command = "1";

                    try
                    {
                        outputStream.write(command.getBytes()); //transmite o valor do comando para o modulo bluetooth
                    }
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                {
                    command = "10";
                    try
                    {
                        outputStream.write(command.getBytes());
                    }
                    catch(IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

                return false;
            }

        });
```

Crash log :

```
12-21 15:57:01.117 14520-14520/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
12-21 15:57:01.117 14520-14520/? D/houdini: [14520] Initialize library(version: 5.0.7a_y.48167 RELEASE)... successfully.
12-21 15:57:01.184 14520-14520/com.example.noazevedo.appbluetoothfinal I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is com.example.noazevedo.appbluetoothfinal, real application class is null.
12-21 15:57:01.426 14520-14520/com.example.noazevedo.appbluetoothfinal V/Monotype: SetAppTypeFace- try to flip, app = com.example.noazevedo.appbluetoothfinal
12-21 15:57:01.427 14520-14520/com.example.noazevedo.appbluetoothfinal V/Monotype:     Typeface getFontPathFlipFont - systemFont = default#default
12-21 15:57:01.430 14520-14520/com.example.noazevedo.appbluetoothfinal V/Monotype: SetAppTypeFace- try to flip, app = com.example.noazevedo.appbluetoothfinal
12-21 15:57:01.430 14520-14520/com.example.noazevedo.appbluetoothfinal V/Monotype:     Typeface getFontPathFlipFont - systemFont = default#default
12-21 15:57:01.596 14520-14520/com.example.noazevedo.appbluetoothfinal W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
12-21 15:57:01.633 14520-14520/com.example.noazevedo.appbluetoothfinal V/Monotype: SetAppTypeFace- try to flip, app = com.example.noazevedo.appbluetoothfinal
12-21 15:57:01.634 14520-14520/com.example.noazevedo.appbluetoothfinal V/Monotype:     Typeface getFontPathFlipFont - systemFont = default#default
12-21 15:57:01.873 14520-14584/com.example.noazevedo.appbluetoothfinal D/OpenGLRenderer: Render dirty regions requested: true
12-21 15:57:01.879 14520-14520/com.example.noazevedo.appbluetoothfinal D/Atlas: Validating map...
12-21 15:57:01.941 14520-14584/com.example.noazevedo.appbluetoothfinal I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
12-21 15:57:01.942 14520-14584/com.example.noazevedo.appbluetoothfinal W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
12-21 15:57:01.952 14520-14584/com.example.noazevedo.appbluetoothfinal D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
12-21 15:57:13.907 14520-14520/com.example.noazevedo.appbluetoothfinal E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
12-21 15:57:13.907 14520-14520/com.example.noazevedo.appbluetoothfinal E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
12-21 15:57:13.909 14520-14520/com.example.noazevedo.appbluetoothfinal E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.io.OutputStream.write(byte[])' on a null object reference
                                                                                               at com.example.noazevedo.appbluetoothfinal.MainActivity$1.onTouch(MainActivity.java:70)
                                                                                               at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8382)
                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
                                                                                               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2314)
                                                                                               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1692)
                                                                                               at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2781)
                                                                                               at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:63)
                                                                                               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2275)
                                                                                               at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8578)
                                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4021)
                                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3887)
                                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
                                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
                                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
                                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3578)
                                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
                                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3635)
                                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
                                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
                                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
                                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
                                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
                                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5701)
                                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5675)
                                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5646)
                                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5791)
                                                                                               at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
                                                                                               at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
                                                                                               at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
                                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5264)
                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:900)
                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:695)
12-21 15:57:13.909 14520-14520/com.example.noazevedo.appbluetoothfinal D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


                                                                                         --------- beginning of crash
12-21 15:57:13.909 14520-14520/com.example.noazevedo.appbluetoothfinal E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                         Process: com.example.noazevedo.appbluetoothfinal, PID: 14520
                                                                                         java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.io.OutputStream.write(byte[])' on a null object reference
                                                                                             at com.example.noazevedo.appbluetoothfinal.MainActivity$1.onTouch(MainActivity.java:70)
                                                                                             at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8382)
                                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
                                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
                                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
                                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
                                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
                                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
                                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
                                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
                                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
                                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
                                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
                                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
                                                                                             at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2314)
                                                                                             at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1692)
                                                                                             at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2781)
                                                                                             at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:63)
                                                                                             at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2275)
                                                                                             at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8578)
                                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4021)
                                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3887)
                                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
                                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
                                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
                                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3578)
                                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
                                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3635)
                                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
                                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
                                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
                                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
                                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
                                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5701)
                                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5675)
                                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5646)
                                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5791)
                                                                                             at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
                                                                                             at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
                                                                                             at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5264)
                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:900)
                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:695)
```

Comment: can you add the crash log ?

Comment: i have edited the question with the crash log included now

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're probably getting NPE as `outputStream` has not been initialized.

Comment: Im new to this , how can i initialize it?

Comment: How you initialize it will depend on what you're using it for....see following for some examples https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/io/outputstream/java-io-outputstream-example/

Comment: I read the examples , i want the outputstream to get the value of the String " command " and send it , i saw the " writting characters method but im not sure how to implement it.